# How to start my application after device completing reboot process?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, startup, android-broadcast

I have created an app, I want to open it after the device restart I am using a broadcast receiver but not working , What can I do, any alternative solution for this.

I have tested on 5.1 as well 10,11

**here is my receiver**

```
package com.activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
public class StartActivityOnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

**here is my manifest**

```
<receiver android:name="com.activity.StartActivityOnBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Do you have permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`?

Answer (score 1):

at first this line is always `true`

```
if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
```

it should be

```
if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction()))
```

further add proper permission for receiver

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver
    android:name=".StartActivityOnBootReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
```

optionally you may try to split declared `action`s to three separated `intent-filter`s instead of keeping one array

and last but not least: starting Android API 29 you can't start `Activity` from broadcast, check out [DOCs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts)

simple, but imho ugly workaround is to add next permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

with this granted your `Activity` will start also on API 29+